# Call Swift code from Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a simple swift class:

```
@objc public class Wallet: NSObject {
    @objc public func getPrivateKey() -> String {
       return ""
    }
}
```

that i would like to call from Kotlin. I have also created a bridging header that looks like this:

```
#ifndef iosApp_Bridging_Header_h
#define iosApp_Bridging_Header_h

#import "iosApp-Swift.h"

#endif /* iosApp_Bridging_Header_h */
```

and linked it in Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name

In Kotlin Multiplatform project I have defined expect class in common module of the project as follows:

```
expect class WalletMP() {
    fun getPrivateKey() : String
}
```

and in iosMain module i have defined actual class like this:

```
actual class WalletMP actual constructor() {
    actual fun getPrivateKey(): String {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Now, as far as I understand I should be able to call swift wallet class by just defining:

```
val wallet = Wallet()
```

but the swift class is not visible/accessible in Kotlin. Even if I define bridging header like so:

```
#ifndef iosApp_Bridging_Header_h
#define iosApp_Bridging_Header_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Wallet: NSObject
   -(NSString*)getPrivateKey;
@end

#endif /* iosApp_Bridging_Header_h */
```

The problem is the same. What am I missing? Did I forget to set something? I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Not really an answer to your immediate question, but you might find it a lot easier to define an interface in the Multiplatform module and let iOS implement and inject that interface rather than trying to call out to Swift code directly.

Answer (score 5):

By default Kotlin/Native only provides wrappers for built-in iOS libraries (e.g. UIKit, Foundation, etc.). They are located in `platform.*` (e.g. `import platform.UIKit.UIDevice`)

But there are several options to use your own Objective-C (Swift with Objective-C API) code in your Kotlin Multiplatform app.

1. If you are using [Cocoapods gradle plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods-dsl-reference.html) you can create pod locally and cocoa plugin will provide Kotlin wrappers for you. By default you can import your Objective-C API from `cocoapods.<POD_NAME>` (or you can specify your own `packageName`). Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-with-cocoapods-sample/tree/master).
2. Compile your code as static library and use [cinterop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html). You can also use [SwiftKlib](https://github.com/ttypic/swift-klib-plugin) gradle plugin that will built and inject cinterop's for you.
3. Another option, that I highly recommend will be to use DI container, you can create simple DI yourself or pick existing, e.g. [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/). In that case instead of expect/actual approach, you can create common interface:

```kotlin
interface Wallet() {
    fun getPrivateKey(): String
}
```

then implement this interface in iOS and Android apps and set it in DI, example for iOS:

```swift
class IosWallet: Wallet {
  // class definition goes here
}


@main
struct iOSApp: App {
    
    // DI init Call
    init() {
        DI.init(IosWallet())
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        //...
    }
}
```