How to set gradle.property from XCode target with CocoaPods?
I used to use the following script build phase to set buildkonfig.flavor property on kotlin version 1.19.20 and it worked fine:
cd "$SRCROOT/.." && ./gradlew :shared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode -P buildkonfig.flavor=prod

But since updating to kotlin to version 2.0.0, it does not compile and says:
'embedAndSign' task can not be used in a project with dependencies to pods.

I tried switching to any other task like build, assemble or generateBuildKonfig, and moving the build phase up and down the list. It compiles & runs, but the property is not set.
Upon reverting back to original versions it turns out that the flavor is also not set when using other tasks instead of embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode.
So I guess the question is:
What other task can I use to set gradle property from XCode target's build phases instead, since the embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode is now prohibited for CocoaPods?

According to this it seems to be fixed but using 2.0.0 keeps failing with the same message

Hmm, I have found another thread, but I have to admit: I don't understand it very much. It sure does not work for me on 2.0.0.

I mean, I don't know if they are trying to make embedAndSign work again with CocoaPods or prohibit it from working

Ok, so I finally figured it out (kind of).
Running embedAndSign task in a CocoaPods project to set a gradle.properties is wrong. As discussed in the original issue, it can lead to linking issues and generally does not make much sense, as the shared module is already build as a pod.
The gradle.properties cannot be set directly from the XCode project with CocoaPods. Information about the target/flavor should be instead passed into the shared module using iOS configurations.
First edit your iOS configurations so the name contains the target name. It can be done in project settings under the Info tab and CocoaPods should then automatically create corresponding configuration files under the Pods folder. Then edit each target scheme so the corresponding configuration is used.
The configuration name is then automatically passed to the gradle when building the module inside the shared.podspec:
"$REPO_ROOT/../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework \
    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME \
    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS" \
    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration="$CONFIGURATION"

After that you have to map the new iOS configurations to corresponding NativeBuildTypes:
xcodeConfigurationToNativeBuildType["iOSConfigName"] = NativeBuildType.DEBUG

The configuration name can then be accessed inside the shared module using findProperty(KotlinCocoapodsPlugin.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTY) and gradle.properties can be set according to it using the setProperty method.
For more details see github thread that talks specificaly about setting a flavor for the shared module based on target.

Unfortunately with the release of Kotlin 2.0.0-Beta5 the embedAndSign task isn't possible anymore, since Jetbrains deactivated it.
YouTrack issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-64096/Diagnostic-when-embedAndSign-used-for-framework-with-cocoapods-dependencies#focus=Comments-27-9849651.0-0
GitHub commit:
https://github.com/jetbrains/kotlin/commit/7ab691fcef9eb91eae4771efc17ffd3170c297db

Thanks for clarifying (Im gonna assume you meant that as a comment, but didn't have enough reputation.)
Still though, now that it's clear they prohibited it, I am looking for an alternative to that for my use case.

Hi, yes I meant that as a comment. Afaik there's currently no solution for it. But there different ways of running swift code inside your CMP app. Check the following SO answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77545882/20329236
